# Django 1.7 Template_Dirs Agony

Tags: django

Alright I am going bonkers.  I have just updated to Django 1.7 and am attempting to start the server using manage.py.  I receive the "TEMPLATE_DIR must be a tuple" error....however the bloody thing IS a tuple, at least as far as I can tell and also according to print(type(TEMPLATE_DIRS)).  Here is the code:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS =(
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        )
```

The result produces:

('/var/templates',)

and returns `<class 'tuple'>` when I print out the type.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: do you have multiple settings.py files?

Comment: joel....you are a gentleman and a scholar, and I am an idiot.  I was modifying settings.py in the general directory and not the directory of my project...   --->fool